# Enter Turkey for the second time on a different passport

Tags: automobiles, turkey, multiple-entry, repeat-visits, motorcycles

I am currently in Turkey on a 90 day entry with **Passport A**. I am planning on leaving Turkey, but returning after the visa runs out to transit through the country further.

Because I have dual citizenship, can I re-enter again but on **Passport B** to claim a further 90 days?

An important aspect to this is I am travelling with a vehicle by land, so there is no alternative route. The vehicle's number has been registered on the Turkish immigration system when I first entered the country.

Comment: Generally the presence time limits are *per person* and not *per passport*... YMMV with how it may end up being enforced.

Answer (score 5):

> It is not possible for foreigners holding two passports to stay in Türkiye for 90 days each with their two different passports within the last 180 days.

https://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa

Thanks @littleadv, somehow I managed to find my own answer with the correct keywords.